# How to detect a click on the selected row of a RadGridView control

Tags: wpf, events, routed-events

My WPF application uses the Telerik RadGridView control on a few of its screens.  I have a requirement that says that whenever the user clicks on a row in the RadGridView, I'm supposed to switch to another screen and display detail information about that row.  I hooked up a handler to the SelectionChanged event and this works, except that nothing happens if the user clicks on the selected row a second time.  This makes sense, as the selected row isn't being changed.

How can I detect a second click on the same row and have the second screen displayed?

Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just attach a handler to the **MouseUp** event on the GridView.  Check if there are any selected cells and respond from there.  This will fire even if there is already a selection.

The MouseDown event will fire on the mouse click, but before the gridview updates the selction, mouse up should fire when the selection has already been adjusted

You can also attach a handler to each individual cell in code-behind as follows

```
(this.GridView as RadGridView).AddHandler(  
     GridViewCell.MouseUpEvent,  
     new EventHandler<Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventArgs>(this.OnMouseUp));
```

Comment: Attaching to each individual cell will allow you to avoid having the selection update if the grid is 2nd left clicked somewhere outside the cell that did not cause the selection to change

Comment: I completely forgot about this question.  I implemented a `MouseUp` event handler on the forms where it was needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try to achieve this through the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event or `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event.